# Yii::$app->user->can внутри widget?

Tags: php, yii2

```
namespace app\components\widgets;

use yii\base\Widget;
use Yii;

class LeftMenuWidget extends Widget {

    public $menu = array();

    public function init() {
        if (Yii::$app->user->can('Просмотр заявок Ожидание')) {
            $this->menu = array(
                'name' => '1'
            );
        }
        parent::init();
    }

    public function run() {
        return $this->render('leftMenu', ['menu' => $this->menu]);

    }

}
```

Почему проверка на операцию не проходит?
условие `can('Просмотр заявок Ожидание')` возвращает `false`.

Когда использую в контроллере, все нормально

Comment: А если обратный слэш добавить? `\Yii::$app->user......`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский тоже самое

Comment: А где находится ваш виждет? В какой папке?

Comment: @Razzwan создана мной (components -> widgets), может ее импортировать? как?

Answer (score 1):

Кодировка файла была 1251.
Изменив на UTF-8 проблема ушла:) 
Текст can () то на русском языке :)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в коде виджета:

```
use Yii;
```

Comment: Уже давно прописан. Не работает